# React Admin - How to dynamically change tab title so browser history list is decipherable?

Tags: react-admin

Setting `<Admin>`'s `title` [prop](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#title) to a "Admin" causes the tab to always be called "Admin" regardless of which view the user is on. That makes the browser history list difficult to navigate because every history entry says "Admin".

What are ways to dynamically change it depending on which page is being shown?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Javascript you can try

```
document.title = "new title here";
```